Get Value by Name of Nested Json Array
I wonder how it's possible to get a value out of a nested JSON Array.
On first level, it's actually working like this for me:
name := ((JSONValue as TJSONArray).Items[i] as TJSonObject).Get('meta_data').JSONValue.Value;

I tried different versions of .Get like:
.Get('meta_data.94.key').JSONValue.Value

or
.Get(['meta_data'],['94'],['key']).JSONValue.Value

I have no idea how it should work, as I am absolute beginner.
This is one item of the array, otherwise it's too long to post here.
[{"id":1457,"name":"#1919 Schl\u00fcsselanh\u00e4nger Nassau","slug":"1919-schluesselanhaenger-nassau","permalink":"https:\/\/www.xxxxxx.biz\/produkt\/1919-schluesselanhaenger-nassau\/","date_created":"2019-04-10T15:07:08","date_created_gmt":"2019-04-10T13:07:08","date_modified":"2024-01-03T07:56:00","date_modified_gmt":"2024-01-03T06:56:00","type":"simple","status":"publish","featured":false,"catalog_visibility":"visible","description":"<p>Pfiffiger Schl\u00fcsselanh\u00e4nger mit Heizungs-Entl\u00fcftungs-Schl\u00fcssel und sch\u00f6nem, breiten Flachring.<br \/>\nDie gro\u00dfe Werbefl\u00e4che bietet viel Platz f\u00fcr Ihr Logo als Lasergravur, Druck oder Pr\u00e4gung.<\/p>\n<h3 id=\"bulk-price-table\"><\/h3>\n","short_description":"<p>Schl\u00fcsselanh\u00e4nger Nassau<\/p>\n","sku":"1919","price":"","regular_price":0,"sale_price":"","date_on_sale_from":null,"date_on_sale_from_gmt":null,"date_on_sale_to":null,"date_on_sale_to_gmt":null,"on_sale":false,"purchasable":false,"total_sales":0,"virtual":false,"downloadable":false,"downloads":[],"download_limit":-1,"download_expiry":-1,"external_url":"","button_text":"","tax_status":"taxable","tax_class":"","manage_stock":false,"stock_quantity":null,"backorders":"no","backorders_allowed":false,"backordered":false,"low_stock_amount":null,"sold_individually":false,"weight":"28","dimensions":{"length":"","width":"","height":""},"shipping_required":true,"shipping_taxable":true,"shipping_class":"","shipping_class_id":0,"reviews_allowed":false,"average_rating":"0.00","rating_count":0,"upsell_ids":[],"cross_sell_ids":[],"parent_id":0,"purchase_note":"","categories":[{"id":101,"name":"Schl\u00fcsselanh\u00e4nger Heizungsentl\u00fcftung","slug":"schluesselanhaenger-heizungsentlueftung"}],"tags":[{"id":51,"name":"Schl\u00fcsselanh\u00e4nger","slug":"schluesselanhaenger"}],"images":[{"id":899,"date_created":"2019-04-01T01:04:00","date_created_gmt":"2019-03-31T21:04:00","date_modified":"2021-03-31T12:28:16","date_modified_gmt":"2021-03-31T08:28:16","src":"https:\/\/www.xxxxxx.biz\/wp-content\/uploads\/2019\/03\/1919.jpg","name":"1919","alt":"1919"}],"attributes":[{"id":2,"name":"Zolltarifnummer","slug":"pa_zolltarifnummer","position":0,"visible":true,"variation":false,"options":["79070000000"]},{"id":3,"name":"Werbeanbringung","slug":"pa_werbeanbringung","position":1,"visible":true,"variation":false,"options":["Druck","Gravur"]},{"id":4,"name":"Werbefl\u00e4che","slug":"pa_werbeflaeche","position":3,"visible":true,"variation":false,"options":["27 x 15 mm"]},{"id":5,"name":"Abmessungen","slug":"pa_abmessungen","position":4,"visible":true,"variation":false,"options":["88 x 22 x 10 mm"]},{"id":6,"name":"Material","slug":"pa_material","position":5,"visible":true,"variation":false,"options":["Metall"]}],"default_attributes":[],"variations":[],"grouped_products":[],"menu_order":0,"price_html":"","related_ids":[1452,1469,1461,1466,1451],"meta_data":[{"id":42499,"key":"_woosea_brand","value":""},{"id":42500,"key":"_woosea_mpn","value":""},{"id":42501,"key":"_woosea_upc","value":""},{"id":42502,"key":"_woosea_ean","value":""},{"id":42503,"key":"_woosea_gtin","value":""},{"id":42504,"key":"_woosea_optimized_title","value":""},{"id":42505,"key":"_woosea_unit_pricing_measure","value":""},{"id":42506,"key":"_woosea_unit_pricing_base_measure","value":""},{"id":42507,"key":"_woosea_condition","value":""},{"id":42508,"key":"_woosea_age_group","value":""},{"id":42509,"key":"_woosea_installment_months","value":""},{"id":42510,"key":"_woosea_installment_amount","value":""},{"id":42511,"key":"_woosea_exclude_product","value":"no"},{"id":42512,"key":"_woosea_cost_of_good_sold","value":""},{"id":42513,"key":"_woosea_multipack","value":""},{"id":42514,"key":"_woosea_is_bundle","value":""},{"id":42515,"key":"_woosea_energy_efficiency_class","value":""},{"id":42516,"key":"_woosea_min_energy_efficiency_class","value":""},{"id":42517,"key":"_woosea_max_energy_efficiency_class","value":""},{"id":42518,"key":"_et_pb_post_hide_nav","value":"default"},{"id":42519,"key":"_et_pb_page_layout","value":"et_right_sidebar"},{"id":42520,"key":"_et_pb_side_nav","value":"off"},{"id":42521,"key":"_et_pb_use_builder","value":""},{"id":42522,"key":"_et_builder_version","value":"BB|Divi|3.22.7"},{"id":42523,"key":"_et_pb_first_image","value":""},{"id":42524,"key":"_et_pb_truncate_post","value":""},{"id":42525,"key":"_et_pb_ab_stats_refresh_interval","value":"hourly"},{"id":42526,"key":"_et_pb_old_content","value":""},{"id":42527,"key":"_et_pb_enable_shortcode_tracking","value":""},{"id":42528,"key":"_et_pb_custom_css","value":""},{"id":47624,"key":"_product_url","value":""},{"id":47625,"key":"_button_text","value":""},{"id":47626,"key":"_max_variation_sale_price","value":""},{"id":47627,"key":"_min_variation_sale_price","value":""},{"id":47628,"key":"_max_variation_regular_price","value":""},{"id":47629,"key":"_min_variation_regular_price","value":""},{"id":47630,"key":"_max_variation_price","value":""},{"id":47631,"key":"_min_variation_price","value":""},{"id":52885,"key":"_wcj_product_images_meta_custom_on_single","value":""},{"id":52886,"key":"_wcj_product_images_meta_custom_on_archives","value":""},{"id":52887,"key":"_wcj_product_images_hide_image_on_single","value":"no"},{"id":52888,"key":"_wcj_product_images_hide_thumb_on_single","value":"no"},{"id":52889,"key":"_wcj_product_images_hide_image_on_archives","value":"no"},{"id":52890,"key":"_woosea_is_promotion","value":""},{"id":52891,"key":"_woosea_custom_field_0","value":""},{"id":52892,"key":"_woosea_custom_field_1","value":""},{"id":52893,"key":"_woosea_custom_field_2","value":""},{"id":52894,"key":"_woosea_custom_field_3","value":""},{"id":52895,"key":"_woosea_custom_field_4","value":""},{"id":52896,"key":"_unit_base","value":""},{"id":52897,"key":"_unit_product","value":""},{"id":52898,"key":"_unit_price_auto","value":"no"},{"id":52899,"key":"_unit_price_regular","value":""},{"id":52900,"key":"_unit_price","value":""},{"id":52901,"key":"_unit_price_sale","value":""},{"id":52902,"key":"_mini_desc","value":""},{"id":52904,"key":"_free_shipping","value":"no"},{"id":52905,"key":"_service","value":"no"},{"id":52906,"key":"_differential_taxation","value":"no"},{"id":52907,"key":"_ts_gtin","value":""},{"id":52908,"key":"_ts_mpn","value":""},{"id":58759,"key":"_metaseo_metadesc","value":"#1919 Schl\u00fcsselanh\u00e4nger Nassau"},{"id":58889,"key":"_metaseo_metatitle","value":"#1919 Schl\u00fcsselanh\u00e4nger Nassau"},{"id":77834,"key":"bm_customer_price_type","value":"fix"},{"id":77835,"key":"bm_customer_copy_for_group","value":"copy"},{"id":77837,"key":"bm_industrie_price_type","value":"fix"},{"id":77838,"key":"bm_industrie_copy_for_group","value":"copy"},{"id":77840,"key":"bm_autohaus_price_type","value":"fix"},{"id":77841,"key":"bm_autohaus_copy_for_group","value":"copy"},{"id":77843,"key":"bm_psi_price_type","value":"fix"},{"id":77844,"key":"bm_psi_copy_for_group","value":"copy"},{"id":77846,"key":"bm_guest_price_type","value":"fix"},{"id":77847,"key":"bm_guest_copy_for_group","value":"copy"},{"id":77848,"key":"bm_customer_bulk_copy_for_group","value":"copy"},{"id":77850,"key":"bm_industrie_bulk_copy_for_group","value":"copy"},{"id":77851,"key":"bm_autohaus_bulk_copy_for_group","value":"copy"},{"id":77853,"key":"bm_psi_bulk_copy_for_group","value":"copy"},{"id":77854,"key":"bm_guest_bulk_copy_for_group","value":"copy"},{"id":77855,"key":"_unit","value":""},{"id":77856,"key":"_sale_price_label","value":""},{"id":77857,"key":"_sale_price_regular_label","value":""},{"id":77858,"key":"_min_age","value":""},{"id":77859,"key":"_et_pb_truncate_post_date","value":""},{"id":85824,"key":"_min_guest_price","value":"0"},{"id":85825,"key":"_min_guest_price_saved","value":"2022-06-27-07-04"},{"id":94707,"key":"_min_psi_price","value":"0"},{"id":94708,"key":"_min_psi_price_saved","value":"2022-01-14-10-26"},{"id":113253,"key":"_delivery_time_countries","value":[]},{"id":113254,"key":"_gzd_version","value":"3.15.5"},{"id":113255,"key":"_hs_code","value":""},{"id":113256,"key":"_manufacture_country","value":"0"},{"id":113257,"key":"_yoast_wpseo_metadesc","value":"%%sitename%% Pfiffiger Schl\u00fcsselanh\u00e4nger mit Heizungs-Entl\u00fcftungs-Schl\u00fcssel und sch\u00f6nem, breiten Flachring."},{"id":113258,"key":"_yoast_wpseo_content_score","value":"90"},{"id":113259,"key":"_yoast_wpseo_estimated-reading-time-minutes","value":"1"},{"id":173666,"key":"bm_psi_bulk_prices","value":{"1":{"bulk_price":"1.6","bulk_price_from":"500","bulk_price_to":"999","bulk_price_type":"fix"},"2":{"bulk_price":"1.4","bulk_price_from":"1000","bulk_price_to":"1999","bulk_price_type":"fix"}}},{"id":221924,"key":"bm_all_customers_copy_for_group","value":"copy"},{"id":221925,"key":"bm_all_customers_bulk_copy_for_group","value":"copy"},{"id":221926,"key":"_defect_description","value":""},{"id":221927,"key":"_allergen_ids","value":[]},{"id":221928,"key":"_warranty_attachment_id","value":""},{"id":221929,"key":"_photovoltaic_system","value":"no"},{"id":221930,"key":"_used_good","value":"no"},{"id":221931,"key":"_defective_copy","value":"no"},{"id":221932,"key":"_is_food","value":"no"},{"id":221933,"key":"_customs_description","value":""},{"id":221934,"key":"_is_non_returnable","value":"no"},{"id":221935,"key":"_yoast_wpseo_primary_product_cat","value":""},{"id":221936,"key":"_yoast_wpseo_primary_product_nutrient","value":""},{"id":221937,"key":"_yoast_wpseo_wordproof_timestamp","value":""},{"id":295905,"key":"_et_dynamic_cached_shortcodes","value":[]},{"id":295906,"key":"_et_dynamic_cached_attributes","value":{"title_font":"|700|||||||","sale_badge_font":"|700|||||||","price_font":"|700|||||||","sale_price_font":"|700|||||||"}}],"stock_status":"instock","has_options":false,"post_password":"","global_unique_id":"","yoast_head":"<!-- This site is optimized with the Yoast SEO plugin v23.5 - https:\/\/yoast.com\/wordpress\/plugins\/seo\/ -->\n<title>#1919 Schl\u00fcsselanh\u00e4nger Nassau &#8212; Gifts &amp; Promotion<\/title>\n<meta name=\"description\" content=\"Gifts &amp; Promotion Pfiffiger Schl\u00fcsselanh\u00e4nger mit Heizungs-Entl\u00fcftungs-Schl\u00fcssel und sch\u00f6nem, breiten Flachring.\" \/>\n<meta name=\"robots\" content=\"index, follow, max-snippet:-1, max-image-preview:large, max-video-preview:-1\" \/>\n<link rel=\"canonical\" href=\"https:\/\/www.xxxxxx.biz\/produkt\/1919-schluesselanhaenger-nassau\/\" \/>\n<meta property=\"og:locale\" content=\"de_DE\" \/>\n<meta property=\"og:type\" content=\"article\" \/>\n<meta property=\"og:title\" content=\"#1919 Schl\u00fcsselanh\u00e4nger Nassau &#8212; Gifts &amp; Promotion\" \/>\n<meta property=\"og:description\" content=\"Gifts &amp; Promotion Pfiffiger Schl\u00fcsselanh\u00e4nger mit Heizungs-Entl\u00fcftungs-Schl\u00fcssel und sch\u00f6nem, breiten Flachring.\" \/>\n<meta property=\"og:url\" content=\"https:\/\/www.xxxxxx.biz\/produkt\/1919-schluesselanhaenger-nassau\/\" \/>\n<meta property=\"og:site_name\" content=\"Gifts &amp; Promotion\" \/>\n<meta property=\"article:modified_time\" content=\"2024-01-03T06:56:00+00:00\" \/>\n<meta property=\"og:image\" content=\"https:\/\/www.xxxxxx.biz\/wp-content\/uploads\/2019\/03\/1919.jpg\" \/>\n\t<meta property=\"og:image:width\" content=\"800\" \/>\n\t<meta property=\"og:image:height\" content=\"800\" \/>\n\t<meta property=\"og:image:type\" content=\"image\/jpeg\" \/>\n<meta name=\"twitter:card\" content=\"summary_large_image\" \/>\n<meta name=\"twitter:label1\" content=\"Gesch\u00e4tzte Lesezeit\" \/>\n\t<meta name=\"twitter:data1\" content=\"1 Minute\" \/>\n<script type=\"application\/ld+json\" class=\"yoast-schema-graph\">{\"@context\":\"https:\/\/schema.org\",\"@graph\":[{\"@type\":\"WebPage\",\"@id\":\"https:\/\/www.xxxxxx.biz\/produkt\/1919-schluesselanhaenger-nassau\/\",\"url\":\"https:\/\/www.xxxxxx.biz\/produkt\/1919-schluesselanhaenger-nassau\/\",\"name\":\"#1919 Schl\u00fcsselanh\u00e4nger Nassau &#8212; Gifts &amp; Promotion\",\"isPartOf\":{\"@id\":\"https:\/\/www.xxxxxx.biz\/#website\"},\"primaryImageOfPage\":{\"@id\":\"https:\/\/www.xxxxxx.biz\/produkt\/1919-schluesselanhaenger-nassau\/#primaryimage\"},\"image\":{\"@id\":\"https:\/\/www.xxxxxx.biz\/produkt\/1919-schluesselanhaenger-nassau\/#primaryimage\"},\"thumbnailUrl\":\"https:\/\/www.xxxxxx.biz\/wp-content\/uploads\/2019\/03\/1919.jpg\",\"datePublished\":\"2019-04-10T13:07:08+00:00\",\"dateModified\":\"2024-01-03T06:56:00+00:00\",\"description\":\"Gifts &amp; Promotion Pfiffiger Schl\u00fcsselanh\u00e4nger mit Heizungs-Entl\u00fcftungs-Schl\u00fcssel und sch\u00f6nem, breiten Flachring.\",\"breadcrumb\":{\"@id\":\"https:\/\/www.xxxxxx.biz\/produkt\/1919-schluesselanhaenger-nassau\/#breadcrumb\"},\"inLanguage\":\"de-DE\",\"potentialAction\":[{\"@type\":\"ReadAction\",\"target\":[\"https:\/\/www.xxxxxx.biz\/produkt\/1919-schluesselanhaenger-nassau\/\"]}]},{\"@type\":\"ImageObject\",\"inLanguage\":\"de-DE\",\"@id\":\"https:\/\/www.xxxxxx.biz\/produkt\/1919-schluesselanhaenger-nassau\/#primaryimage\",\"url\":\"https:\/\/www.xxxxxx.biz\/wp-content\/uploads\/2019\/03\/1919.jpg\",\"contentUrl\":\"https:\/\/www.xxxxxx.biz\/wp-content\/uploads\/2019\/03\/1919.jpg\",\"width\":800,\"height\":800,\"caption\":\"1919\"},{\"@type\":\"BreadcrumbList\",\"@id\":\"https:\/\/www.xxxxxx.biz\/produkt\/1919-schluesselanhaenger-nassau\/#breadcrumb\",\"itemListElement\":[{\"@type\":\"ListItem\",\"position\":1,\"name\":\"Startseite\",\"item\":\"https:\/\/www.xxxxxx.biz\/\"},{\"@type\":\"ListItem\",\"position\":2,\"name\":\"Produkte\",\"item\":\"https:\/\/www.xxxxxx.biz\/shop\/\"},{\"@type\":\"ListItem\",\"position\":3,\"name\":\"#1919 Schl\u00fcsselanh\u00e4nger Nassau\"}]},{\"@type\":\"WebSite\",\"@id\":\"https:\/\/www.xxxxxx.biz\/#website\",\"url\":\"https:\/\/www.xxxxxx.biz\/\",\"name\":\"Gifts & Promotion 2023\",\"description\":\"\",\"publisher\":{\"@id\":\"https:\/\/www.xxxxxx.biz\/#organization\"},\"potentialAction\":[{\"@type\":\"SearchAction\",\"target\":{\"@type\":\"EntryPoint\",\"urlTemplate\":\"https:\/\/www.xxxxxx.biz\/?s={search_term_string}\"},\"query-input\":{\"@type\":\"PropertyValueSpecification\",\"valueRequired\":true,\"valueName\":\"search_term_string\"}}],\"inLanguage\":\"de-DE\"},{\"@type\":\"Organization\",\"@id\":\"https:\/\/www.xxxxxx.biz\/#organization\",\"name\":\"Ambassador Int. GmbH & Co. KG\",\"url\":\"https:\/\/www.xxxxxx.biz\/\",\"logo\":{\"@type\":\"ImageObject\",\"inLanguage\":\"de-DE\",\"@id\":\"https:\/\/www.xxxxxx.biz\/#\/schema\/logo\/image\/\",\"url\":\"https:\/\/www.xxxxxx.biz\/wp-content\/uploads\/2019\/05\/ambass.png\",\"contentUrl\":\"https:\/\/www.xxxxxx.biz\/wp-content\/uploads\/2019\/05\/ambass.png\",\"width\":600,\"height\":102,\"caption\":\"Ambassador Int. GmbH & Co. KG\"},\"image\":{\"@id\":\"https:\/\/www.xxxxxx.biz\/#\/schema\/logo\/image\/\"}}]}<\/script>\n<!-- \/ Yoast SEO plugin. -->","yoast_head_json":{"title":"#1919 Schl\u00fcsselanh\u00e4nger Nassau &#8212; Gifts &amp; Promotion","description":"Gifts &amp; Promotion Pfiffiger Schl\u00fcsselanh\u00e4nger mit Heizungs-Entl\u00fcftungs-Schl\u00fcssel und sch\u00f6nem, breiten Flachring.","robots":{"index":"index","follow":"follow","max-snippet":"max-snippet:-1","max-image-preview":"max-image-preview:large","max-video-preview":"max-video-preview:-1"},"canonical":"https:\/\/www.xxxxxx.biz\/produkt\/1919-schluesselanhaenger-nassau\/","og_locale":"de_DE","og_type":"article","og_title":"#1919 Schl\u00fcsselanh\u00e4nger Nassau &#8212; Gifts &amp; Promotion","og_description":"Gifts &amp; Promotion Pfiffiger Schl\u00fcsselanh\u00e4nger mit Heizungs-Entl\u00fcftungs-Schl\u00fcssel und sch\u00f6nem, breiten Flachring.","og_url":"https:\/\/www.xxxxxx.biz\/produkt\/1919-schluesselanhaenger-nassau\/","og_site_name":"Gifts &amp; Promotion","article_modified_time":"2024-01-03T06:56:00+00:00","og_image":[{"width":800,"height":800,"url":"https:\/\/www.xxxxxx.biz\/wp-content\/uploads\/2019\/03\/1919.jpg","type":"image\/jpeg"}],"twitter_card":"summary_large_image","twitter_misc":{"Gesch\u00e4tzte Lesezeit":"1 Minute"},"schema":{"@context":"https:\/\/schema.org","@graph":[{"@type":"WebPage","@id":"https:\/\/www.xxxxxx.biz\/produkt\/1919-schluesselanhaenger-nassau\/","url":"https:\/\/www.xxxxxx.biz\/produkt\/1919-schluesselanhaenger-nassau\/","name":"#1919 Schl\u00fcsselanh\u00e4nger Nassau &#8212; Gifts &amp; Promotion","isPartOf":{"@id":"https:\/\/www.xxxxxx.biz\/#website"},"primaryImageOfPage":{"@id":"https:\/\/www.xxxxxx.biz\/produkt\/1919-schluesselanhaenger-nassau\/#primaryimage"},"image":{"@id":"https:\/\/www.xxxxxx.biz\/produkt\/1919-schluesselanhaenger-nassau\/#primaryimage"},"thumbnailUrl":"https:\/\/www.xxxxxx.biz\/wp-content\/uploads\/2019\/03\/1919.jpg","datePublished":"2019-04-10T13:07:08+00:00","dateModified":"2024-01-03T06:56:00+00:00","description":"Gifts &amp; Promotion Pfiffiger Schl\u00fcsselanh\u00e4nger mit Heizungs-Entl\u00fcftungs-Schl\u00fcssel und sch\u00f6nem, breiten Flachring.","breadcrumb":{"@id":"https:\/\/www.xxxxxx.biz\/produkt\/1919-schluesselanhaenger-nassau\/#breadcrumb"},"inLanguage":"de-DE","potentialAction":[{"@type":"ReadAction","target":["https:\/\/www.xxxxxx.biz\/produkt\/1919-schluesselanhaenger-nassau\/"]}]},{"@type":"ImageObject","inLanguage":"de-DE","@id":"https:\/\/www.xxxxxx.biz\/produkt\/1919-schluesselanhaenger-nassau\/#primaryimage","url":"https:\/\/www.xxxxxx.biz\/wp-content\/uploads\/2019\/03\/1919.jpg","contentUrl":"https:\/\/www.xxxxxx.biz\/wp-content\/uploads\/2019\/03\/1919.jpg","width":800,"height":800,"caption":"1919"},{"@type":"BreadcrumbList","@id":"https:\/\/www.xxxxxx.biz\/produkt\/1919-schluesselanhaenger-nassau\/#breadcrumb","itemListElement":[{"@type":"ListItem","position":1,"name":"Startseite","item":"https:\/\/www.xxxxxx.biz\/"},{"@type":"ListItem","position":2,"name":"Produkte","item":"https:\/\/www.xxxxxx.biz\/shop\/"},{"@type":"ListItem","position":3,"name":"#1919 Schl\u00fcsselanh\u00e4nger Nassau"}]},{"@type":"WebSite","@id":"https:\/\/www.xxxxxx.biz\/#website","url":"https:\/\/www.xxxxxx.biz\/","name":"Gifts & Promotion 2023","description":"","publisher":{"@id":"https:\/\/www.xxxxxx.biz\/#organization"},"potentialAction":[{"@type":"SearchAction","target":{"@type":"EntryPoint","urlTemplate":"https:\/\/www.xxxxxx.biz\/?s={search_term_string}"},"query-input":{"@type":"PropertyValueSpecification","valueRequired":true,"valueName":"search_term_string"}}],"inLanguage":"de-DE"},{"@type":"Organization","@id":"https:\/\/www.xxxxxx.biz\/#organization","name":"Ambassador Int. GmbH & Co. KG","url":"https:\/\/www.xxxxxx.biz\/","logo":{"@type":"ImageObject","inLanguage":"de-DE","@id":"https:\/\/www.xxxxxx.biz\/#\/schema\/logo\/image\/","url":"https:\/\/www.xxxxxx.biz\/wp-content\/uploads\/2019\/05\/ambass.png","contentUrl":"https:\/\/www.xxxxxx.biz\/wp-content\/uploads\/2019\/05\/ambass.png","width":600,"height":102,"caption":"Ambassador Int. GmbH & Co. KG"},"image":{"@id":"https:\/\/www.xxxxxx.biz\/#\/schema\/logo\/image\/"}}]}},"hs_code":"","customs_description":"","manufacture_country":"0","shipping_dimensions":{"length":"","width":"","height":""},"unit":[],"unit_price":{"base":"","product":"","price_auto":false,"price":"","price_regular":"","price_sale":"","price_html":""},"mini_desc":"","defect_description":"","min_age":"","gtin":"","mpn":"","sale_price_label":[],"sale_price_regular_label":[],"delivery_time":[],"country_specific_delivery_times":[],"free_shipping":false,"service":false,"used_good":false,"defective_copy":false,"photovoltaic_system":false,"differential_taxation":false,"warranty_attachment_id":"","is_food":false,"food":{"deposit_type":[],"deposit_quantity":1,"deposit":0,"ingredients":"","nutrient_reference_value":"","nutri_score":"","alcohol_content":"","allergen_ids":[],"nutrient_ids":[{"term":0,"value":"","ref_value":""}],"net_filling_quantity":"","drained_weight":"","description":"","distributor":"","place_of_origin":""},"_links":{"self":[{"href":"https:\/\/www.xxxxxx.biz\/wp-json\/wc\/v3\/products\/1457"}],"collection":[{"href":"https:\/\/www.xxxxxx.biz\/wp-json\/wc\/v3\/products"}]}}]

Is it somehow possible to search for bm_psi_bulk_prices for example and then get the positions below this key? In this case, there are three price-ranges, but this can change.


You already know how to use TJSONObject.Get(), so what is stopping you from using it to find nested values? Please [edit] your question to show what you have attempted that is not working for you. Also, show the actual JSON you are processing, not a breakdown of it.

You have to index the desired item in the array, cast the item to TJSONObject, and then call Get()/GetValue() on it for the desired field.  That part you have down.  You just have to repeat that for any nested objects/arrays as needed. For example:
var
  jsonValue: TJSONValue;
  jsonArr: TJSONArray;
  jsonObj: TJSONObject;
  key: string;
  i, j: Integer;
begin
  ...  
  jsonValue := ...;
  i := ...;
  jsonArr := jsonValue as TJSONArray;
  jsonObj := arr.Items[i] as TJSONObject;
  jsonArr := jsonObj.GetValue('meta_data') as TJSONArray;
  for j := 0 to jsonArr.Count-1 do
  begin
    jsonObj := jsonArr.Items[j] as TJSONObject;
    key := jsonObj.GetValue('key').Value;
    if key = 'bm_psi_bulk_prices' then
    begin
      jsonObj := jsonObj.GetValue('value') as TJSONObject;
      // use jsonObj.GetValue('1') and jsonObj.GetValue('2') as needed...
      Break;
    end;
  end;
  ...
end;

